# Хранение временных данных в Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Пользователю доступно два фрагмента. В каждом он может работать с данными, - предположим, несколькими числами и массивом, состоящим из `string`.

Как организовать хранение этих данных во время жизни приложения? Если хранить данные локально, в рамках каждого фрагмента, то они теряются при переходе.

На текущий момент есть два варианта: static-класс и public переменные в Activity. Существуют ли еще варианты? Если нет, то опишите недостатки и преимущества каждого подхода.

Comment: База данных вероятно придумана для таких вещей

Comment: В моем понимании база данных требуется для длительного хранения данных, разве не так?

Comment: Не совсем понятно из вашего вопроса что вообще происходит.

Comment: Переменные в активности можно потерять вместе с активностью - при повороте экрана, и даже кратковременном сворачивании/переходе в другую активность. Если хранить в активности, то нужно озаботиться сохранением/восстановлением в `onSave/RestoreInstanceState`. Если хранить статически (синглтон, например) - то тут обратный эффект, активность давно закрыта и не нужна, а данные могут дожить до следующего запуска. А могут и не дожить - тут ничего не гарантировано. Ну и при сворачивании и переходе в другое приложение их тоже можно потерять.

Comment: Мне необходимо, чтобы они - переменные - существовали до закрытия приложения. Главная проблема - фрагменты. При переходе между ними данные теряются. Отсюда два варианта хранения, описанные в вопросе.

Comment: 1. база данных (как уже предложили)
2. shared preference (по сути аналогично первому варианту)
3. сделать переменные в MyApp, а экземпляр myapp можно получить примерно таким способом `MyApp.get(getActivity()).getMyVariable()`. Ваши переменные будут существовать пока живет MyApp (его надо указать в манифесте).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы описываете нужно делать через сохранение состояния фрагмента.

Для этого есть методы `onSaveInstanceState()` - для сохранения данных и `onRestoreInstanceState()` для восстановления. Восстановить, также, можно и в `onCreate()` и в `onViewCreated()`.

Все эти методы имеют `Bundle` в качестве аргумента. В него в `onSaveInstanceState()` можно положить данные и они будут переданы при вызове остальных методов при восстановлении фрагмента.

Однако, чтобы это работало, вы должны не создавать новые фрагменты каждый раз, но отображать ранее созданные, в которых данные были сохранены. Возможно именно в этом у вас проблема.